# mysql/sql server: SELECT @@identity

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, identity

is there a difference in the way this functions between the two databases mysql and sql server:

```
SELECT @@identity
```

Comment: Is there something particular you are looking for?

Comment: Do not EVER use @@identity in SQl Server. Use scope_identity() or the output clause instead. @@identity will destroy your data integrity when someo addsa trigger that inserts to another table with an identity. Since you can't guarantee this won't happen, it is an unsafe at any speed kind of thing.

Comment: @HLGEM: [Good point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526256/mysql-sql-server-select-identity/3526315#3526315)! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) in SQL Server to avoid issues with triggers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: Since that doesn't appear to be in the ANSI SQL standard, it is left to the DBMS vendor to roll their own methods.

```
mysql_insert_id()
```